# What happened to DOM level 1?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

So, what happened to the **DOM level 1**?

For example, there are **DOM level 0** events like this

```
window.onload = func;
element.onclick = func;
```

and there is **DOM level 2** (and now even level **3**) events

```
element.addEventListener("click", func, false);
```

However, there is no mention anywhere about **DOM level 1** events? Was it like with *Lesuire suit Larry 4* that got lost before it was ever released or was the nr 1 just skipped or didn't the level 1 include anything related to the events?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**DOM Level 0 isn't an actual spec**, DOM Level 0 is just what we call DOM/JS features before the DOM was released. The W3C released DOM Level 1 in 1998. Prior to that there was no DOM spec.

There was no events model in DOM Level 1, it was released in DOM Level 2.

Comment: Ok, thanks - if Level 0 was not an actual spec, then it makes things a lot clearer

Answer (score 5):

[**Document Object Model (HTML) Level 1**](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/level-one-html-971209.html)

> The Level 1 document does not include mechanisms to access and modify style specified through CSS-1. *Furthermore, it will not define an event model for HTML documents.* This functionality will be specified in a future Level of this specification. The events that are supported in Level 0 are given in the DOM Level 1 HTML ECMAScript binding for completeness; the method of defining and handling events is expected to change.